# Did North Korea really say "it's not a problem that our country goes dark at night"?

Tags: north-korea

According to [the Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/north-korea-it-s-not-problem-country-goes-dark-night-10033200.html) and many other US journals, about North Korea:

> An editorial in the state-run newspaper, the Rodong Sinmun, claims
> that the country is not weakened by its lack of electricity and that
> other countries could soon find themselves in the same situation.

I could not find this in the journal, mostly because I don't know Korean and the English version of the website might be not very well translated.

Is there a way I can confirm this information in the journal?

Comment: While I can't comment on that particular statement, it should be noted that there are a good many people who think of dark skies at night as a good thing, and possibly North Korea's only redeeming feature: https://www.darksky.org/

Comment: So I went to Rodong's website (rodong.rep.kp/en) and typed in the exact keyphrase "essence of society is not on flashy lights" and it returned that I don't have the permission to access the page. Then it IP banned me from the site.